# Netlogo ...compare a a turtle variable to patch variable on which it is standing

Tags: netlogo

I would like to compare a turtle variable with the patch variable on which it is standing.

```
 ask  patches with [ pcolor = green and inventory > 0]
```

`[ ask one-of turtles-here`
      `[if myself [ conviction] > detection )`

Conviction is a turtle variable and detection is a patch variable. Can it be done. This is my first posting. So apologies if the format is not correct.

Answer (score 3):

A turtles has direct access to the variables of the patch under it:

```
turtles-own [ conviction ]
patches-own [ detection ]

to go
  ask patches [
    ask one-of turtles-here [
      if conviction > detection [ ; the turtle accesses both variables directly
        ; do something
      ]
    ]
  ]
end
```